# How to adjust rear hub on Giant ATX 2?

Tags: hub

My back wheel on my Giant ATX 2 2019 is wobbly, so I am trying to adjust it. I saw many videos on how to do this. For [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOUsVXUBnAE), but none of them feature the type of hub that I have. It seems like an axle and skewer in one part (see photos below)

My question is: how to adjust this particular type of hub? Also, what is this type of hub called?

[image]

this is how the wheel looks like without the axle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My son's ATX2 2019 axle snapped in the very same spot and he's only 58 kg (128 lb).

Comment: @GottaPlan interesting, the good people of https://www.giant-bicycles.com/ should take a note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a perfectly standard hub with a freewheel, the problem is that the axle is broken, so it has come out of the hub along with the skewer. It explains the wobbly feeling. Kudos for noticing that in the first place.

Any basic hub overhaul tutorial should suit, but you need to replace the axle first, as part of the process.

Comment: thanks for that! do you know how do i buy that replacement axle? what is the part number? also, a tutorial that you recommend?

Comment: is this the part that i need? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071X2C4L1

Comment: The linked part should work. You will also need a freewheel removal tool. The freewheel must be removed to install the axle. I would reuse the spacers and jam nuts to maintain your current spacing. It might be worth a trip to your local bike shop and procure some new bearings to match your new cones.